# How can I add new rows into a grouped data frame in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm wondering if there is a way to group a data frame based on two variables and then add new rows if a certain string, such as a name, is not present within the grouped data.

I have a list of dummy names (`name_list`) that I'd like to ensure are included in the grouped data irrespective of whether they were there in the first place or not (based on the `name` column). For example, I'd like to group by `date` and `drill`, but you'll note `Person A` and `Person B` are missing from `2023-01-01`/`Activity 1`. I'd like to make sure every name from `name_list` is included for every combination of `date`/`drill`, and if names are added, they are assigned a `duration` of 0 to essentially represent they were not present for that `date`/`drill` combination. Hope that makes sense. Thanks.

```
library(tidyverse)

# List of names to be joined within grouping variables.
name_list <- c(paste("Person", LETTERS[1:8]))

set.seed(10)
name <- c(name_list[3:8], name_list[1:6], name_list[2:7], name_list[3:8])
date <- rep(seq(as.Date('2023/01/01'), as.Date('2023/01/02'), by = "day"),
            each = 12)
drill <- rep(paste("Activity", 1:2), each = 6, times = 2)
duration <- rep(c(5, 8), each = 6, times = 2)

df <- data.frame(name, date, drill, duration)

       name       date      drill duration
1  Person C 2023-01-01 Activity 1        5
2  Person D 2023-01-01 Activity 1        5
3  Person E 2023-01-01 Activity 1        5
4  Person F 2023-01-01 Activity 1        5
5  Person G 2023-01-01 Activity 1        5
6  Person H 2023-01-01 Activity 1        5
7  Person A 2023-01-01 Activity 2        8
8  Person B 2023-01-01 Activity 2        8
9  Person C 2023-01-01 Activity 2        8
10 Person D 2023-01-01 Activity 2        8
11 Person E 2023-01-01 Activity 2        8
12 Person F 2023-01-01 Activity 2        8
13 Person B 2023-01-02 Activity 1        5
14 Person C 2023-01-02 Activity 1        5
15 Person D 2023-01-02 Activity 1        5
16 Person E 2023-01-02 Activity 1        5
17 Person F 2023-01-02 Activity 1        5
18 Person G 2023-01-02 Activity 1        5
19 Person C 2023-01-02 Activity 2        8
20 Person D 2023-01-02 Activity 2        8
21 Person E 2023-01-02 Activity 2        8
22 Person F 2023-01-02 Activity 2        8
23 Person G 2023-01-02 Activity 2        8
24 Person H 2023-01-02 Activity 2        8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `complete()` function.

###### EDIT:

As mentioned by @LMc, using `complete` only works, if all the values of `name` already exist in the data. Setting the `name`column to a factor with all possible names of `name_list` solves this issue.

```
df %>% 
        mutate(name = factor(name, levels = name_list)) %>% 
        complete(name, date, drill, fill = list(duration = 0))

# A tibble: 32 × 4
   name     date       drill      duration
   <fct>    <date>     <chr>         <dbl>
 1 Person A 2023-01-01 Activity 1        0
 2 Person A 2023-01-01 Activity 2        8
 3 Person A 2023-01-02 Activity 1        0
 4 Person A 2023-01-02 Activity 2        0
 5 Person B 2023-01-01 Activity 1        0
 6 Person B 2023-01-01 Activity 2        8
 7 Person B 2023-01-02 Activity 1        5
 8 Person B 2023-01-02 Activity 2        0
 9 Person C 2023-01-01 Activity 1        5
10 Person C 2023-01-01 Activity 2        8
11 Person C 2023-01-02 Activity 1        5
12 Person C 2023-01-02 Activity 2        8
13 Person D 2023-01-01 Activity 1        5
14 Person D 2023-01-01 Activity 2        8
15 Person D 2023-01-02 Activity 1        5
16 Person D 2023-01-02 Activity 2        8
17 Person E 2023-01-01 Activity 1        5
18 Person E 2023-01-01 Activity 2        8
19 Person E 2023-01-02 Activity 1        5
20 Person E 2023-01-02 Activity 2        8
21 Person F 2023-01-01 Activity 1        5
22 Person F 2023-01-01 Activity 2        8
23 Person F 2023-01-02 Activity 1        5
24 Person F 2023-01-02 Activity 2        8
25 Person G 2023-01-01 Activity 1        5
26 Person G 2023-01-01 Activity 2        0
27 Person G 2023-01-02 Activity 1        5
28 Person G 2023-01-02 Activity 2        8
29 Person H 2023-01-01 Activity 1        5
30 Person H 2023-01-01 Activity 2        0
31 Person H 2023-01-02 Activity 1        0
32 Person H 2023-01-02 Activity 2        8
```

Comment: I would add that this only works if all the values of `name` exist in the data already. If "Person A" is not in the data at all this will not work. You will need to create a factor first: `factor(name, levels = name_list)` and then you will likely want to change that back to a character variable after `complete`.